# Shiny Binary Check boxes

Tags: r, shiny

I was wondering if its possible for Shiny checks boxes to observe each other in the UI such that if I were to check one, the other must be unchecked, vice versa.

I came across the function updateCheckBox but the example shown is used for the server side, is it possible for checkboxes to communicate between each other on the UI side?

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing that jQuery was designed for: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+uncheck+checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually what radio buttons are used for, see `?radioButtons`. Is there a reason those wouldn't work here?